# Monitoring for wireless clients on any network

Tags: networking, wifi

Is there a way to monitor for **any** client over **any** local wireless network. Or even detects clients not associated with a network.

I can see `airodump-ng` and `kismet` do something like that, but I'm not sure this is the best way.

All I need is the MAC of the clients.

Comment: That is the way

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to setup monitoring in an uplayer device. You may check these solutions:
http://www.wfiltertutorial.com/WFilter_Wireless